# What is Hidan's Source of Power?

Tags: naruto

[image]

Hidan is probably the most misunderstood character in Naruto. He has the ability to survive pretty much anything (including decapitation), and is able to remote-injure opponents whose blood he tasted, and while he's inside his cursed circle.

Where did this power come from? What kind of technique is that? Every single technique used in Naruto so far has been explained to some degree, besides this one.

Do anyone has some information to shed light on the technique? From the Data Book perhaps?

Comment: He says he gets his power from his god but I'm sure there's a better explanation out there.

Comment: Not according to the databook. Check my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the official character databook](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Naruto-Official-Character-Data-Book/dp/1421541254/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1355321724&sr=8-1):

> The Way of Jashin uses bodies of believers in forbidden jutsu rituals. Hidan was the first successful test case.
>
> As a reward for his many massacres, Hidan acquires an immortal body via the Way of Jashin. This only helps to affirm his love for the Way.

It adds:

> Thou shalt kill thy neighbor. This dogma is contradictory since it would allow devotees to kill each other. But to Hidan who is immortal, this is meaningless. That is why he is able to accept the doctrine and follow its teachings. Even if he ends up with just his head...

It also adds, regarding his motivations:

> The Way of Jashin is absolute for Hidan, the only thing worth believing in. He considers his supreme purpose to be to spread the Way of Jashin to nonbelievers throughout the world. It means to create a world that acknowledges mass killing. And Hidan feels that this is possible by being a part of the Akatsuki.

And this is about it, regarding to info on Hidan on the databook.

Comment: This explains why he is immortal, but the technique itself is not explained, no? Nice answer anyways. :)

Comment: I see, but it still doesn't explain what the technique is. Is it some sort of Yin-Yang element technique? What does it take from you? Does that mean this "Jashin" god truly exist in the Naruto universe?

Comment: Indeed. But the databook gives no hints about the technique.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Considering that the databook states that he gets his immortality from the rituals, I'd say Jashin really exists.