# Is that jutsu really the Edo Tensei?

Tags: naruto

I know the title probably needs to be changed, but I wasn't sure how to put it spoiler-free.
The question follows as a block, for its 'spoilery' nature for anyone who hasn't seen Naruto Shippuden up to episode 290.

> In this episode Kabuto summons several shinobi using [Edo Tensei](http://www.leafninja.com/ninjutsu-03.php#Edo). For this jutsu we know that a living body to act as receptacle and a piece of DNA from the one being revived are needed. The summoner will then use a tag to control the summoned soul's personality.
>  Kabuto explains to Naruto and Sakura that the water in the "Hole" is so rich that he was able to create life with those weird snakes embedded with Orochimaru's chakra. I assume this means that the body that comes out of the water is the living body that serves as sacrifice. I assume this because Hidan's eyes look like those of the ones summoned by Edo Tensei. And afterwards Kabuto inserts a tag in this Hidan, to control his personality.
>  Considering that Hidan was really summoned by Edo Tensei, however, there is the fact that his body does not look 'complete'. But then again, I don't think we've ever seen a naked Edo Tensei summoned body, so we cannot be sure if this is normal or not.
>
>  So basically:
>  **Is this some weird jutsu that really *looks like* Edo Tensei?**
>  **Or should we assume that Hidan as died and this was *really* Edo Tensei?** (It *is* possible that Hidan is dead, if you take into consideration what is explained in [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/209/what-is-hidans-source-of-power/211#211) answer)

Comment: Those last two lines should be in a comment. :) But nice attitude! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's Edo Tensei. I have yet to have seen a coffin, even in later episodes.

Technically, Hidan never died. He's was still buried (in pieces) in the hole Shikamaru put him in. Kabuto took those pieces, and using the water and his snakes, he managed to revive him completely. Somewhat like a clone.

> (Much like he did with Dark Naruto in the following episodes)

Answer (score 1):

The episode you cite is the first one of a saga filler, which means it's original material, present in the Anime only. So there's no Manga canon to answer it, because it doesn't come from there.