# How Kabuto could reincarnate or manifest Hidan (in an anime filler)?

Tags: naruto

In episode 290 of Naruto Shippuden, Kabuto creates Hidan from thousands of tiny snakes. But by looking at the eyes of manifested Hidan, it seems like an Edo-Tensei. And Kabuto mentions it himself.

Hidan isn't dead! Then how can he be reincarnated? What Jutsu is that??

In the manga of course there is no confusion..

But for that episode I am trying to find the logic. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: No idea for as far as I know. They didn't give much explanation and the whole filler saga looked like someone chewed on some mushrooms while writing it, so I doubt we'll ever get an explanation.

Comment: [Related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/451/49)

Comment: how did I miss that question? @JNat, the problem with these duplicate question is, the search goes by 'string' in question title and tries to bring related stuffs.. When I posted the question, I didn't get this question as relative!

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' That's because when the site first started, people were a bit over eager in their use of the spoiler block in questions which makes them near impossible to search.  It's getting better though!

Comment: @MCeley, I hope so

Comment: I think Hidan can die (by hunger, etc...), but not be killed. (by someone else using physical attacks)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Hidan in that filler is not necessarily the real Hidan. You said it by yourself "Kabuto creates Hidan from thousands of tiny snakes" which proves my point here. In Naruto we see many things created from snakes, in this case, It is Hidan. 
The directer of this filler tried to make his story interesting but he failed miserably as you can see. This filler overlaps with the real story making the answer for your question not very logical. This is as far as you can get with this event.

Answer (score 2):

The reincarnated Hidan was like a clone created by Kabuto from the real one's DNA, and also it wasn't like the other Edo Tensei, he died later without being sealed.

Comment: clone makes the most sense. Like orochimaru.. essentially all the orochimarus we see are just pieces of him manifested into something that looks like the original. We see this when sasuke revives him from anko mitarashi's shoulder during the 4th great ninja war.

Answer (score 0):

this is just an opinion, but hidan never died in the first place. I mean, sure, he got blown up, but he never died, since he is immortal. maybe hidan's consciousness was put into the body that kabuto created with some sort of mind transfer jutsu.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Hidan can die from malnutrition, so one can assume that while he was trapped in that hole that Shikamaru dug for him, he eventually and inevitably died from said cause. That's the only explanation that I can give as to how this even makes a lick of sense since I'm re-watching the series and just got to this filler episode, haha.

Answer (score 0):

By a bunch of snakes and a scroll, to revive a real corpse through edo tensei you need their dna for it

that was just a clone of him cultivated from his cells